# Oracle select statement syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

Today i discovered that this select statement is valid in oracle.

```
select * from table where col=(value)
```

and equivelant to this

```
select * from table where col=value
```

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Is there any language where `(1+1)` is not equal to `1+1` ?

Comment: Only accountants would consider `(value)` to be equivalent to `-value` :)

Comment: Jeffrey where in my q did i imply this? Thanks anyway for your constructive guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
/* Result:
"DUMMY"
"X"
*/

SELECT  COUNT(dummy) FROM DUAL WHERE dummy = 'X';
-- 1

SELECT  COUNT(dummy) FROM DUAL WHERE dummy = ('X');
-- 1

SELECT  COUNT(dummy) FROM DUAL WHERE dummy = (((('X'))));
-- 1

SELECT    COUNT(dummy)
FROM      DUAL
WHERE     dummy = 'X'
OR        dummy = ('X')
OR      ( dummy = 'X' OR dummy = ('X'))
OR      ((dummy = 'X' OR dummy = ('X')) AND (1 = 1 OR (1 = 1 OR (1 = 1))));
-- 1
```

> (…) parentheses or brackets are used to explicitly denote precedence
>   by grouping parts of an expression that should be evaluated first.
>   Thus, to force addition to precede multiplication, we write (2 + 3) ×
>   4 = 20, and to force addition to precede exponentiation, we write (3 +
>   5)2 = 64.

- Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: Yes i know the order of operations. Maybe it just looked a bit weird when i saw the statement and didnt really think a lot before posting the q. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what explanation you are looking for. If you meant why col=value and col=(value) are same then this is perfectly valid not only in oracle but in most of the other dbs sql queries. Consider below scenario when u need similar situation.

`Select * from table1 
where col = (Select max(col2) from table2)`